# How do I store void method result into int array method

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to store the result of public static void readGrades() into method array int[]grades. But I fail to do so. I tried ArrayList and other stuff but unfortunately.

```
public static int[]grades;
public static void main(String[] args) {
        readGrades();
}
public static void readGrades(){
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many students there are : ");
    int numberOfStudents=in.nextInt();
    for(int i=1;i<=numberOfStudents;i++){
    System.out.print("Enter the grade of the students : ");
    int grades1=in.nextInt();
    grades1++;
}
```

Comment: you need to learn how to use array in java. you haven't store data in grades[] array. This code >>                   int grades1=in.nextInt();
    grades1++; >> just creates an variable and reinitialized it in next iteration
    }

Comment: You can't because a `void` method *doesn't return* anything.

Comment: @Christian If you take a closer look at code you will see that `grades` is static field, so this method is kind of static setter which means it should return void.

Comment: @Pshemo if one of them would be not static, it would not be possible  basically?

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, it works like a *setter*, but it [**doesn't return anything. Nor `void`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html).

Comment: @Mr.Sarunov Why not? You could make this method an field non-static. Later in `main` method you just create instance of your class and execute this method from that instance.

Comment: @Christian I wasn't clear. I meant that void should be return type, not that code should return void (`return ;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this :

```
public static int[] grades;
public static void main(String[] args) {
        readGrades();
}
public static void readGrades(){
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many students there are : ");
    int numberOfStudents=in.nextInt();
    grades=new int[numberOfStudents];
    for(int i=0;i<numberOfStudents;i++){
        System.out.print("Enter the grade of the students : ");
        int grade=in.nextInt();
        grades[i]=grade;
     }
}
```

You have to know that this will store data in `grades` array and you can use it anter calling the method readGrades() , try to write code that print grades after readGrades().

Comment: Cheers,it helped me out:)

Comment: this will leave index[0] as unused.

Comment: @Sanjeev yes I know. You can change that by removing +1 from numberOfStudents and in loop for setting i=0 and i<numberOfStudents.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to declare `grades[] static`, you can do it with a `locally declared int[]` as well, something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many students there are : ");
        int numberOfStudents=in.nextInt();
        int[] grades = new int[numberOfStudents];
        readGrades(grades, in);
        // here you can write code to play with grades array
}
public static void readGrades(int[] grades, Scanner in){
    for(int i=0;i<numberOfStudents;i++){
         System.out.print("Enter the grade of the students : ");
         grades[i]=in.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is helpful as well,cheers. However I am asked to do it like i Showed.